# I get "LaTeX Error: File `figure/minimal-boring-plots1' not found." running knitr-minimal.lyx

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, lyx

LyX Version 2.1.1
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
MikTex ver 2.9

I have just installed LyX and cannot get plots in the output.  I can get basic knitr examples with no plots to complie to a pdf.

If I View[Ctrl-R] the file knitr-minimal.lyx from within LyX I get the above error message, "LaTeX Error: File `figure/minimal-boring-plots1' not found." with description:
" ...\linewidth]{figure/minimal-boring-plots1}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2"

However, if I save the knitr-minimal.Rnw file to my R work directory, then run the R script:
require(knitr)
rnwfile <- "knitr-test.Rnw"
knit(rnwfile)

This will produce a TeX file, knitr-minimal.tex, in my work directory, that MikTeX compiles correctly to a pdf with plots included.

I assume I have something setup incorrectly in LyX:(

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
bob

Comment: What version of knitr are you using? If you are using version 1.6, can you try using version 1.5? To do that, do `remove.packages(knitr)` in R (confirm that it is removed by trying to load it), and then install http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/knitr/knitr_1.5.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty.  I was using knitr version 1.6.  When I try to install knitr 1.5 and get an error message:> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
This a problem with our zip program.  I'll try to work on it

Answer (score 4):

My bad.  The problem was in the setup of LyX.  Instead of allowing the default working directory in the LyX setup I choose the one I wanted to use and some combination of LyX, knitr, and laTeX could not deal with that.  After I reset the working directory to the temp directory the packages can now communicate and a pdf with plots was produced.  Sorry for the inconvenience.  bob

Comment: Thanks for getting back with the solution. Glad you got it figured out.